# ASP.NET Core 3.1 / 5 WeatherForecast sample Web API project throws error 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net5

I create an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API project in Visual Studio 2019, with just one controller per default and its returning a http 404 error.

This is the controller (very simple)

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

and when I call `http://localhost:5000/weatherforecast` it always returns http 404.

PS: I'm using macos

Any help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I found the url's path is right, I suggest you could check the startup.cs to make sure you have add the below codes:

Inside ConfigureServices method:

```
       services.AddControllers();
```

Inside Configure method:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

If adding these still not working, please upload the startup.cs codes to let us find the reason why this route doesn't work well.

Comment: For me  app.MapControllers(); was missing in Program.cs of my WebApiCore project

Answer (score 0):

It is an API , not a Rest service. Try this

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
   
    public string Get()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

and url

```
http://localhost:5000/api/weatherforecast/get
```